# AngularJS setting up a function to prevent duplication

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function

At the moment I have duplicate code where I have the following examples:

```
if ($scope.user.window.title == 'true'){
    if (this.title){
        title = '<h2>'+this.title+'<h2>';
    } else {
        title = '';
    }
} else {
    title = '';
}

if ($scope.user.window.football == 'true'){
    if (this.football){
        football = '<p>'+this.football+'<p>';
    } else {
        football = '';
    }
} else {
    football = '';
}
```

I have tried the following but it doesn't work, it says that the `$scope.user.window.football` and `$scope.user.window.title` don't exist. I think it is down to the below function sending the value through as a string for my `$scope`.

```
function CheckWindow(element,tag) {
    console.log(element);
    if ($scope.user.window.element == 'true'){
        if (this.element){
            element = '<'+tag+'>'+this.element+'</'+tag+'>';
        } else {
            element = '';
        }
    } else {
        element = '';
    }
}
```

**Usage**

`CheckWindow('title','h2')`

`CheckWindow('football','p')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `$scope.user.window.element` tries to access the property named `element` of `$scope.user.window`. You need `$scope.user.window[element]` instead.
2. `this` refers to the created function's scope. You could pass a new argument `that` for example.
3. `that.element` will have to be rewritten to `that[element]`, for the same reason as in #1.
4. You can't assign a new value to a function's parameter (well, you can, but it won't be accessible outside the function's scope). Better return the value.

So:

```
function CheckWindow(that, element, tag) {
    if ($scope.user.window[element] && that[element]){
            return '<'+tag+'>'+that[element]+'</'+tag+'>';
    }
    return '';
}

title = CheckWindow(this, 'title', 'h2');
football = CheckWindow(this, 'football', 'p');
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$scope.user.window[element]
```

When you need to reference a property as a sttring, you must use bracket notation.
Also, I doubt that 'this' will reference what you want. You may need to angular.bind this to the method.